# Python Extracting numeric value from {'$date': {'$numberLong': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}}

Tags: dataframe, unix-timestamp, strsplit, data-preprocessing, information-extraction

I am having trouble extracting a numeric value from a pandas DF column. I have a data frame converted from Json and it contains column values like *Image "1"*;

[*Image 1*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNim8.png)

As you can imagine the thing I need is unix timestamp values from this 'dict'. While type of this spesific column is pandas.core.series.Series, values are listed as 'dict'. I am looking for a more general approach to this problem since I also have other columns formated this way like *Image2* ;

[*Image2*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqktw.png)

So far I tried numerous .read commands with spesific delimeters. I tried casting dict into other formats, converting df part to a list and many other things I cant even recall.

Thank you in advance. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I casted dic into str with;

df_date = pd.DateFrame()
df_date['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].astype(str)

and then;

df_date = df['TimeStamp'].str.split("'", expand=True) ##
("'" is delimiter identification and ' is my target delimiter)

this code above gave me a data frame with 6 columns, column no:5 was my expected UnixTimeStamp values so I replaced it with the original df column with this;

df['Date'] = df_date[5]

this solved my problem.